# form checkbox show and hide function wrong way round

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a basic form setup and I'm looking to get an input field to show or hide depending if the checkbox is clicked, currently, the field is showing and when the checkbox is clicked it hides how do I flip this so it's the other way around.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.checkbox input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
      $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('.ch_for').toggle();
    })
  });
```

```css
.hide
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="" class="container1">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="top" class="top">Speak to One of Our Experts</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="ch_name[2]" value="phone">phone</label>
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="ch_name[3]" value="email">email</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="ch_for[3]" value="" placeholder="enter details"  class="form-control ch_for">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="info" class="info">this will have some text here</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="Request-button" class="btn btn-success">REQUEST A CALL BACK</button>
          </div>
```

as you can see from the snippet when you click the button the input field becomes hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked in the following manner...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.checkbox input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
     // logic for box checked
  } else {
    // logic for box unchecked
  }
})
```

});

Comment: Yes, you may want to handle the toggle differently for checked/unchecked side of the branch.